# using MPI_BYTE to receive any data-type

Tags: c, mpi

I have some particular problem: in a simple MPI_Send/MPI_Recv program, it is assumed that we know the type of message we are about to send, but at the receiving end we don't know which type of data we will receive.

SO I try first attempt as follows:

```
    #include "mpi.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int args, char** argv){
            int rank, size;
            MPI_Status status;
            MPI_Init(&args,&argv);
            MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
            MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

            if(rank==0){
                    int x = 10;
                    MPI_Send(&x,4,MPI_BYTE,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            if(rank==1){
                    void* datax;
                    int count = sizeof(int);
                    datax = malloc(count);
                    MPI_Recv(datax,count,MPI_BYTE,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                    //Now check if the value is received correctly
                    int z = (int) datax;
                    printf("RCV: %d \n",z);
            }

            MPI_Finalize();
            return 0;
    }
```

the program compiles correctly and also run, but the received value is some memory garbage value not the correct one (10 in this case).

Any suggestion please?

thanks,

Comment: hmmm :( My mistake in casting the void* type to int value. It works with int  z = *(int *) datax;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although your comment addresses your programming mistake, there is a much better way to send and receive data of unknown types (and even unknown size) in MPI.

One common way to differentiate different message types is to use different tag numbers for each type. In your code, you are using a tag number of 0 in your `MPI_Send` call. Use a tag number that describes the the type of message, and then use [`MPI_Probe`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Probe.html)  before your `MPI_Recv` call to find out what type of message you are about to receive. For example, your code could be modified like so:

```
if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Send(data_buf, data_size, MPI_BYTE, 1, tag_that_describes_message_type, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
} else if (rank == 1) {
    MPI_Status status;
    // Probe for a message coming from rank 0 with any tag.
    MPI_Probe(0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    // Find out what type of message is ready to be received by accessing the MPI_TAG variable in the status struct
    if (status.MPI_TAG == 0) {
        // Receive messages of this type. Maybe you sent an array of ints?
        MPI_Recv(...)
    } else if (status.MPI_TAG == 1) {
        // Receive messages of this type. Maybe you sent an array of floats? Handle it here.
        MPI_Recv(...)
    } else if ...
```

`MPI_Probe` can also be used to find out the size of a message before you receive a message, which allows you dynamically receive virtually any type of message. For a better explanation and illustration of using `MPI_Probe` for this purpose, go to [this tutorial](http://www.mpitutorial.com/dynamic-receiving-with-mpi-probe-and-mpi-status/).

If you need to send widely-different types of data (too many to enumerate with tag numbers), pack your messages into a [Google Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), receive it as an array of `MPI_BYTE`s (as you do in your example), and then unpack it on the receiving side. A C implementation of Protocol Buffers is [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/).

Comment: Kednall, thank you very much! that looks very neat and generic to use :) thanks

Comment: @kendall, I try to take a look that the tutorial link you provide. nice and clear tutorial :). I have one question though, Do you think the use of MPI_prob is recommended in-terms of performance? . what I understand from the tutorial is that : "MPI_Probe will block for a message with a matching tag and sender" this means each time you will have a blocking operation just to check the status info or item to be received (e.g.tag, size, or rank_of_sender); followed by another blocking operation MPI_Recv to really receive the message. Isn't good idea to avoid such operation if possible? thanks.

Comment: @hankol You are very welcome! In regards to performance, you may be confused about what it means to 'block' for a message. Blocking for a message simply means that a process must wait until a message is available to be received. If MPI_Send has already completed on the sending process, MPI_Probe and MPI_Recv will have not block since a message is already available.

Also, since I call MPI_Probe before MPI_Recv, MPI_Probe has already done any necessary blocking (i.e. waiting for the message), so MPI_Recv will not have to block.

Check out MPI_Iprobe and MPI_Irecv if you want to not block at all